# Convert ASP.NET MVC 4 project from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

A client is requesting I convert an application I built in MVC 4 using .NET 4.5 down to .NET 4. Is this possible? What are the steps? I am using VS 2012 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your project->Select properties (alt+enter), the settings window should pop up. The first tab on the left hand side is "Application" select that. Look for the label "Target Framework". Select whatever target you want. You may get compile errors due to reference or functions no longer existing.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to simply target the .NET 4 Framework in Project Properties. You may have to refactor code if you used anything specific to 4.5 (or find workarounds).